# Why's .closest() removing the entire table when I only want it to remove the specific row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to only remove the row (the entire `<tr></tr>`) that the user wants remove.  The check the checkbox followed by clicking `Delete`.  My jquery code below removes the entire table rather than the row the user wants removed when clicking `Delete`.

How can I make it so that the user removes only the row they want to remove?

My jquery code is inside a giant `$document.on('click')...`.

Here's my table:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="question-manager-id" value="7052"></td>
    <td>7052</td>
    <td class="anchor-looking-no-bottom edit-question" data-url="http://localhost.test/games/7052">Some data</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Math</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>math vocab</td>

    <td>
       <label class="switch">
         <input type="checkbox" data-id="7052" class="question-manager-enabled-toggle" checked="">
         <span class="toggle-slider round"></span>
      </label>                        
    </td>

    <td>
      <button class="button small delete-question alert" data-id="7052">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's my jquery (I've added `questionId` variable in case I could somehow use it to only remove the user's chosen row):

```
let questionId = $('.question-manager-id:checked').val(); // returns 7052
$('button.delete-question').closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: Your title says you're using `.closest()` but your code shows `.parents()`. Also, why is your code "inside a giant `$document.on('click')`"?

Comment: I see `.parents('tr')` not `closest`....

Comment: @j08691 sorry that was one of my attempts to rectify this.  `parents()` gave the same outcome

Comment: You are selecting all buttons, you are not selecting a button that is clicked on. Where is your click event handler?

Comment: `$('button.delete-question').on("click", function () {
  const tr = $(this).closest("tr");
});`